# Different Number of Contacts in Smartgroup and CiviMail

Tags: civimail

I have a smart group with about 3000 contacts, but when I create a mailing and add only that group, CiviMail shows the total recipients as 6400+.

I did some research and found [this](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,24743.15.html) but those issues don't apply to us since we are coming up with far more contacts with CiviMail, and our cache timeout is set to 5 minutes.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Comment: Do your contacts have multiple email addresses?  There is an option under admin, civiMail, CiviMail Component Settings for Enable multiple bulk email address for a contact.

Comment: Our contacts only have one email address each.I also just had a look at those civimail settings and that option is unchecked.

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using? Have you been able to test the contacts that are actually being added, to see how they relate to the contacts in the group? Would it be possible to send the mailing as a test on a test server to see how many emails are sent out and to who, and how it compares to the original group?